# Creating a Django South data migration that will populate ImageField from table data

Tags: django, django-south

Sorry about the contrived title, let me explain. I have a Django model with `filename` and `extension` fields, and then there's a static URL where my files are hosted (on S3, not in the database).

I created a South schema migration to add an `ImageField` to my table.

Is it possible to create a South data migration that will populate the `ImageField` for each object, starting from my static URL, the `filename` field, and the `extension` field?

Comment: Sure, url = "s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/images/", filename = "foo", extension = ".jpg".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as simple as:

```
my_image.my_imagefield = my_image.filename + my_image.extension
my_image.save()
```

as the static part of the URL will be handled by Django STATIC_URL automatically.